# MongoDB docs, one-to-many example, why are the references different?

Tags: mongodb

The [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) show an example of a one to many relationship...

(Abbreviated...)

> Model One-to-Many Relationships with Document References
>
> ```
>  // Publisher.
>  {
>     _id: "oreilly",
>     name: "O'Reilly Media",
>  }
>
>  // Book.
>  {
>     _id: 123456789,
>     title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
>     publisher_id: "oreilly"
>  }
>
>  // Book.
>  {
>     _id: 234567890,
>     title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
>     publisher_id: "oreilly"
>  }
> ```

Why is the publisher `_id` a logical, human-readable name while the book `_id`s appear to be generated [surrogate keys?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)

Wouldn't all `_id`s be generated values?

Is it conventional in MongoDB to sometimes use the data itself as a unique key and sometimes not?

If so, when do we use ordinary names ("mary", "joe", "exxon"), and when do we prefer generated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't all _ids be generated values?

MongoDB auto-generates _id only when it is not provided by the user.

> Is it conventional in MongoDB to sometimes use the data itself as a
>   unique key and sometimes not?

Yes, The data can be used as the key. The _id value has to be unique in a collection to correctly identify a document. Any parameter in the document can be set as the _id if it satisfies the above criteria. When the _id is not unique in a collection the duplicate key error is thrown.

> If so, when do we use ordinary names ("mary", "joe", "exxon"), and
>   when do we prefer generated values?

We prefer a generated _id when there is no parameter(or parameter groups), that uniquely identify the document. For example, using the name of a person will not work because, there might come a situation to add another person with the same name. However, consider a books ISBN number, it uniquely identifies a book. Such parameters can be used as _id.

Additional Notes:

- The auto-generated _id has embedded timestamp value (which may be of use).
- No need to worry about duplicate values with auto-generated _id.
- However, an user specified _id value may be more application/domain specific.